# System wouldn't let me choose "not an answer" while reviewing… what is going on??

Tags: discussion, review, answers

A while ago, I was rviewing LQP's, and I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111574/compact-operator-space-is-the-greatest-ideal-of-bh), or more specifically [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113929/135592). My opinion was that it was NAA since it basically restates the question in the form of a hint, as a comment below it says. So I clicked "Recommend Deletion", and… WHAT? Only two comment choices: `No comment needed`, and `This is a link-only answer (and not spam)`. Plus a sort-of warning. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I opened the answer, and flagged it as NAA. I was tempted to flag for mod attention to ask what was going on here, but then I thought I would just do my review via a flag, and hit `Looks OK` on the review queue. So my question is: why did this happen? Why were the choices not present? And what should I have done? Did I take an appropriate course of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a common misconception about that dialog: users think that they are asked to choose a reason for deletion. That's not what it is: the dialog asks you what, **if any**, comment you want to leave for the author. There is no such thing as "reason for deletion"; only close votes are annotated with reasons, not other types of votes.

Your choices are simple: Leave as is, Edit, Delete, Skip (no decision).  Comments are another action, a follow-up to the decision to delete.  The presence or absence of comment options should not affect your decision.

#### Reason for this change

There was a [recent change to the comment options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317464), which the dialog explains: for very old posts, appeals such as "leave a comment instead" are just noise, because nobody feels like digging up a remark they made three years ago and putting it in a comment. *No comment needed* is a good selection for those.